# Tortoise SVN 1.7 Copying file issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Just had something worrying happen now that I am using the newer version of SVN (1.7).

I have an older project which I wanted to copy some CI build scripts over from into a new project. I originally used to use the right click drag and drop then the "Export all versioned items here" or whatever it was called to take a copy of the files without the SVN history.

After not finding that option I did a quick google and found:

http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisesvn/browse_thread/thread/66b30b120756e2ea/47023377b04ef1db?show_docid=47023377b04ef1db

Now I went to just copy and paste my files instead and it for some reason kept the up to date icons in the shell, I thought it may be just the OS not updating the folders so ignored it, and when I went to commit I checked the log to make sure that it wasn't somehow linking to the old project and it said there was no version info.

Anyway now that I actually commit I look in the logs and see all the checkins against the previous repository then mine... So it has my current log entry being the new project, and everything before has the history of the old project... is this a bug or has something gone wrong here?

I dont know why this unrelated repository would have any information from the other unrelated project just from copying the files...

Comment: Perhaps you could you rephrase your question using the exact Subversion terminology: working copy, repository, check-out, commit... As it's now, it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Could you show the part of the repository / repositories and files? At the moment it is unclear which was copied from where to which location.

Comment: I thought the above was fairly concise, I had a check-out of Old-Project, I wanted to export some files from that to another check-out of New-Project (both in separate repositories). I used to select them all and right click drag and drop, then select "Export versioned items here" or something along those lines, then it would just drop the files there. However after reading the link posted, it said you should just normal shell copy, so I did, and yet for some reason when I committed New-Project it contains log entries from Old-Project for those files I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior sounds beneficial. It is beneficial to have the revision history for the files that you copied from the old project. 
If you don't want to see the revision history from the old project you can check the "Stop on Copy/Rename" box in the revision log dialog. 
When you dragged and dropped your files using explorer I suspect you also copied the hidden .svn folder in your old working copy. If you really want to get rid of the revision history, you could have used the repo-browser to go into the repository, select your old project files and export to your new project working copy folder. Then from your new project working copy add the files to your new project repository.

Comment: It may be useful to see how it had changed, but as I didnt do anything but copy a file over it seemed odd, but if this is desired behaviour will give you the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about copying file between two different subversion projects.  If that is what you want, checkout the files in one "working-copy" , then recursively delete all the ".svn" folders.  This "converts" the "working-copy" into just a bunch of files (without revision history or a base remote repository).

Since the files are now just a bunch of files, you can copy them into place in the "new" repository and add with with the `svn add ...` command.  Of course, you will also have to check them in.

When you attempt to do cross-repository movement of files, moving a directory from the "old" working copy into the "new" working copy will place ".svn" folders of one working copy into the other working copy.  Since these folders contain bits of the subversion working copy configuration for the directory, you effectively mix up configurations in one working copy.  This often has some pretty undesirable effects.  If I were you, I would simply grab copies of the "important" files and remove the entire repository.  Then I would attempt the operation a second time using newly checkedout repositories (and a watchful eye that you don't copy over ".svn" folders, or that drag-and-drop helps you copy them automatically).

Normally the copying of ".svn" folders is desired *within a working copy* (it's part of what makes tortise possible and nice to use); however, the design of subversion is not such that you can safely copy these folders *between working copies*.